# find records having more than one distinct colum value

Tags: sql, sqlite

Given table `t1` with columns `Id` ( text, primary key ) and `place` (text) like below.

```
+-------+-----------+
|  Id   |   place   |
+-------+-----------+
| abcde |  Santori  |
| bcdef |  Krypt    |
| cdefg |  Bali     |
| defgh |  Bangkok  |
| abcde |  Colombo  |
+-------+-----------+
```

I need to find out the records for `Id`s having more than one distinct `place`. In the above example the output shall be

```
+-------+-----------+
|  Id   |   place   |
+-------+-----------+
| abcde |  Santori  |
| abcde |  Colombo  |
+-------+-----------+
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far to solve the problem?

Comment: `id` cannot be a primary key if there a duplicate values for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is OK for you:

```
SELECT ID, PLACE FROM T1 as A 
WHERE A.ID IN 
(SELECT ID FROM T1 AS B 
GROUP BY ID 
HAVING count(*) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `exists` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.id = t.id and t1.place <> t.place);
```

Answer (score 1):

In a subquery, you need to get `count` of `distinct place` and get the ID. And then use an outer query to fetch all records.

[Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/968fe9/1)

```
select * From T1
where T1.ID in
(select ID from T1
 group by ID
having count(distinct PLACE) > 1
)
```